# Proving that this map is neither open nor closed

Tags: real-analysis

> Let X={(x,y)$\in \mathbb{R}^2  :x \geq$ 0 or y=0}, and let T be the subspace topology on X induced by induced by usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let U be the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Define f:$X \to \mathbb{R}$ by f((x,y)=x for all (x,y) $\in X$. Prove that it is neither open nor closed.

I am really confused on how this problem should be solved . I tried to make some counterexamples but couldn't sucessfully disprove it.

This question was about proving f to be a quotient map and I proved that by definition but I am struck in this.

Can you please spare some time for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{(x,y): 1<y<2, 0 \leq x <1\}$ is an open set in $X$ whose image is not open. $\{(x,\frac  1 x)
: x>0\}$ is a closed set in $X$ whose image is not closed.

Comment: I don't think that first set is open. It's a straight line in the closed right half space.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos is right (+1 for him). But the first example can be corrected by using $[0,1)\times(1,2)$ instead, which is open in $X$ but projects to the same non-open set $[0,1)$ in $Y$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos you are right. I have corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing out.